# Can't find url views when deploying spring boot on WebSphere

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere

I'm starting a simple project in spring boot, right now I just want to show a startup view, but when deploying on a WebSphere 9 server, it appears when I start "Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not Found: /"
and if I put the url of another controller method for example /login
the same error comes out
"Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not Found: /login"
This is my controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String home() {
        return "example"; 
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "example.html"; 

    }
}
```

Create the explame.html in several places of the project to know if spring recognized it in any of them, but I always got the same message, I leave an image of the initial project structure and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.com.ioks</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExampleFirst</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ExampleFirst</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

[structure project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUQpA.png)

UPDATE

I was able to visualize my start view with  / and / login, as I indicated in my controller, it was as @Jalil.Jarjanazy told me in his answer, I put the html file in templates, but not in templates of the empty package that is in src , because when I want to add something there, it shows me the message: "Files created outside of a web content folder will not be included in your deployed Web application.
", I added it in WEB-INF / classes / templates, another very strange thing is that in Eclipse it does not show me the classes folder, but it is in the project, I manually put the html file and ran the project, I think this is not is the proper way to do it, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong, why can't I see the folder classes in eclipse?

Comment: What is context-root of your app? If it is just `/` , there is already `DefaultApplication` deployed on this context root. So either uninstall it, chnage its root context, or change root context of your app.

Comment: Update my question at the end, 
Where can I see the context-root of my application? Sorry I'm new to spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Your ***example.html*** file should be in the ***templates*** folder.

And you should only return the only name of the html file (***example***) in your controller, so no need for the .html.

Comment: When adding the file example.html in the templates folder, the following message appears:
"Files created outside of a web content folder will not be included in your deployed Web application."

What configuration should I add?